# Error configuring Network Audio System [NAS] in RHEL 6 x64

Tags: linux, qt, audio, redhat

I tried to setup NAS (Network Audio System ) in RHEL 6 by two methods:

First, by RPM install,

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -Uvh nas-1.9.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm nas-libs-1.9.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

it gets installed, but I cannot find the service in /etc/init.d/ directory.
only /etc/nas/nasd.conf file gets created. And if I run the command

```
[root@localhost ~]# nasd
Network Audio System Release 1.9.2
Network Audio System Release 1.9.2
Init: Output open(/dev/dsp) failed: No such file or directory

Fatal server error:
could not create audio connection block info
```

Secondly, by Configuring latest tar-ball **nas-1.9.3.src.tar.gz** provided by NAS site.
but the problem is same.

Please help me to install this properly, as I want to get enable the audio for qt based applications, and qt uses NAS for its audio functionalities.

Comment: Afaik Redhat now uses systemd (as in no SysV and thereby no `/etc/init.d`). Secondly `/dev/dsp` is used by `OSS` which hardly any dist uses today. Try installing `OSS` and that part should solve your `/dev/dsp` problems atleast. Sadly I can't help you more with it.

Comment: May I ask why you want to install NAS? As a project it is not exactly dead, but it does seem to be in some sort of hibernation out of which it only comes out every couple of years or so...

Comment: I am using QSound class for my qt application.
It requires Nas support in linux environment for playing .wav files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried Very much by NAS but not succeed to resolve my problem.

Then i used Phonon library to resolve sound issue !!

Thanx anyways for helping me! :)

Answer (score 1):

okay. well it's been a while but...

you dont have enough perms to open the underlying socket.

me@dev  $ strace -o ./nasd.txt nasd -aa -config ./nasd.conf

```
Network Audio System Release 1.9.3
Network Audio System Release 1.9.3
Error binding unix socket: /var/run/nasd/audio0
: Address already in use

Fatal server error:
Cannot establish unix listening socket
```

the appropriate bit is here from the strace

```
ioctl(0, SIOCGIFCONF, {96, {{"lo", {AF_INET, inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}}, {"wlan0", {AF_INET, inet_addr("192.168.1.69")}}, {"usb0", {AF_INET, inet_addr("192.168.15.100")}}}}) = 0
umask(0)                                = 022
mkdir("/var/run/nasd", 0777)            = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
unlink("/var/run/nasd/audio0")          = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 1
bind(1, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nasd/audio0"}, 22) = -1 EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
```

The  unlink("/var/run/nasd/audio0")          = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted) is the clue.

if we copy the nasd.conf locally and tweak the debug value to 1 and run it as root

me@dev $  sudo nasd -aa -config ./nasd.conf

```
config: Maxfrags set to 3
config: Minfrags set to 2
config: Fragsize set to 256
config: Maxfrags set to 3
config: Minfrags set to 2
config: Fragsize set to 256
Network Audio System Release 1.9.3
Network Audio System Release 1.9.3
AuInitPhysicalDevices();
Init: will close device when finished with stream.
Init: will keep mixer device open.
Init: Leaving the mixer device options alone at startup.
Init: openDevice OUT /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p mode 1
Init: openDevice(1) IN /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c mode 0
setupSoundcard(...);
++ Setting up Output device (/dev/snd/pcmC1D0p)
+++ requesting wordsize of 16, got 8
+++ requesting 2 channel(s), got 1 channel(s)
+++ Requesting minimum sample rate of 5000, got 5000
+++ Requesting maximum sample rate of 44100, got 44100
setupSoundcard(...);
++ Setting up Input device (/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c)
+++ requesting wordsize of 8, got 8
+++ requesting 2 channel(s), got 1 channel(s)
+++ Requesting minimum sample rate of 4000, got 4000
+++ Requesting maximum sample rate of 44100, got 44100
initMixer: could not open output mixer device /dev/mixer: No such file or directory
Init: initMixer failed
createServerComponents(...);
closeDevice: out
closeDevice OUT /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p mode 1
closeDevice: in
closeDevice IN /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c mode 0
closeDevice: mixer
closeDevice: leaving mixer device(s) open
```

in my case looks like I need to setup the mixer section but that should nerf *your* error.

EDIT: `initMixer: could not open output mixer device /dev/mixer: No such file or directory` 
This can be fixed by placing `mixer =""` in the nasd.conf (even though the docs state it won't be honoured, it is)

Also: remember to set your AUDIOSERVER env variable

```
export AUDIOSERVER=tcp/localhost:8000
```

Is the default but never hurts to be certain...

Final thoughts:

by default many x server now `-nolisten tcp` and that could be an issue in implementation to consider.

nmap is your friend.

And, for the record, I still haven't actually got an end-to-end system working... 
Hopefully some other kind soul will jump in and point out anything I have missed.

Hope it helps.

I don't have a rhel box... but it's *probably* the same perms issue.
The docs are "thin" at best